# Offline caching in native Qt application

Tags: qt, native, sentry

Is it possible to enable offline error caching with Native Qt sentry-sdk?

I've followed the official docs, and initialized my sdk with the following code:

```
    sentry_options_t* options = sentry_options_new();
    sentry_options_set_dsn( options, SENTRY_URL );
    sentry_options_set_database_path( options, ".sentry-native" );
    sentry_options_set_release( options, QString("%1@%2").arg( PROJECT_NAME ).arg( PROJECT_VERSION ).toStdString().data() );
    sentry_options_set_debug( options, 1 );
    sentry_init( options );
```

I assumed that the `sentry_options_set_database_path( options, ".sentry-native" );` line of code supposed to be the local database for storing all the events and errors when the user is offline. The `.sentry-native` directory exists and is not empty, but the events and errors that happen when I'm offline are not getting sent to Sentry when I get back online.

Answer (score 0):

I made the same experience (not with Qt, but with a regular C++ application).

I've solved the issue by integrating a [Sentry Relay](https://docs.sentry.io/product/relay/getting-started) between the application and the Sentry server. The relay is configured to run in the simplest proxy mode (`relay.mode: proxy`), and to cache envelopes to the disk when offline (`spool.envelopes.path: /var/tmp/sentry_relay_envelopes` for example).

The connection application - relay is always available, so the application does not need to cache any envelopes. The connection relay - server can go off, and this makes the relay start caching. Once the connection is re-established, the relay sends all cached envelopes.